# How to edit TextFX plugin of Notepad++ to have my own timeformat?

Tags: notepad++, plugins

I tried Python Scripting but its not working for me. It throwing unexception. But Text fx is working great to add time. So anyone please help me to edit TextFX plugin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SynWrite simple plugin inserts time as want,
enter into Python file:

```
from sw import *
from datetime import datetime as d

class Command:
    def run(self):
        t = d.now()
        s = '{:02}-{:02}-{:02}'.format(t.year%100, t.month, t.day)
        ed.insert(s)
```